# CreateView weird behaviour. Goes to the wrong view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my urls.py I have a ListView and a CreateView. When I have both the views in the urls patterns, the CreateView shows the html linked to the ListView. But when I remove the ListView from the url patterns, then the CreateView shows the correct html.

### urls.py

If I have it like this, CreateView shows ListView html

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.TopicListView.as_view(), name="topic"),
    path("<topic>/", views.PostListView.as_view(), name="post"),
    path("create/", views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name="create_post")
]
```

This way, the CreateView behaves like I want it to. Shows the correct HTML

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.TopicListView.as_view(), name="topic"),
    path("create/", views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name="create_post")
]
```

### views.py

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = models.ForumPost
    template_name = "forum/post_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        query_set = super().get_queryset()
        return query_set

class CreatePostView(CreateView):
    model = models.ForumPost
    fields = ("title", "description")
    template_name = "forum/create_post.html"
```

Comment: how you use url in html?

Comment: @shafik 
`<button type="button" name="button"><a href="{% url 'forum:create_post' %}">Create Post</a></button>`

Comment: change this to` path("list/", views.PostListView.as_view(), name="post"),`

Comment: but i need to parse in that "topic" for my implementation. My issues are with the CreatePostView, it is showing the wrong html when the PostListView is in the urlpatterns

Comment: Try to change the order of url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason as urls are checking one by one from up to down. So when you have 3 urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.TopicListView.as_view(), name="topic"),
    path("<topic>/", views.PostListView.as_view(), name="post"),
    path("create/", views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name="create_post")
]
```

And try to use `create/` it actually matches `<topic>/` pattern as a string were passed. So what I recommend is to place it to very down:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.TopicListView.as_view(), name="topic"),
    path("create/", views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name="create_post")
    path("<topic>/", views.PostListView.as_view(), name="post"),
]
```

But also it would be better if you add some additional path to urls in order it won't be double-minded like `list/<topic>/`.